# TypeORM Not unique table/alias: 'TABLE_NAME'

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, relationship, typeorm

I am usingNESTJS`WITH`MYSQL`
I am trying to fetch the relational data of an table.
I've two columns related to a common entity.
while I try to fetch data I got follow errors.
am not able to understood how to fix this one.
Any help would be appriciated

```
{
  "exception": {
    "message": "ER_NONUNIQ_TABLE: Not unique table/alias: 'users'",
    "code": "ER_NONUNIQ_TABLE",
    "errno": 1066,
    "sqlMessage": "Not unique table/alias: 'users'",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,}
}
```

Entities are as following

```
@Entity('leave')
export class LeaveEntity {
  
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;
  // relation between approver and user
  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, u => u.id, {
    eager: false,
    cascade: false,
    nullable: true
  })
  approvedBy: UserEntity[];

  // relation between leave and users
  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, user => user.id, {
    eager: false,
    cascade: false,
    nullable: false
  })
  user: UserEntity[];
}
```

SERVICE CODE TO FETCH DATA

```
const qb = getRepository(LeaveEntity)
      .createQueryBuilder("leave")
      .skip(size * (page - 1))
      .take(size)
      .orderBy('leave.created_at', orderBy)
      .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.approvedBy", "users")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.user", "users")
      .select(['leave', 'users.email', 'users.id', 'users.firstName', 'users.lastName'])
const [items, total] = await qb.getManyAndCount();
return {items, total, page: +page, totalPages: Math.ceil(total/size)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you name it same, take a look at your query builder:

```js
      .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.approvedBy", "users")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.user", "users")
```

So at the end your query will end up with smth like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM leave LEFT JOIN users AS users LEFT JOIN users AS users ...
```

To fix that you have to name it different, fe:

```js
      .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.approvedBy", "apu") // as an approved users
      .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.user", "users")
```

and then use your `apu.` prefix in rest of the query

Comment: if am using the suggested solution. it doesn't show related data

Comment: I don't understand what does this image represents

Comment: it should add `approvedBy` key and it's related data.
but am facing weird situation only any one of the key is working.

Comment: Eeeee there is something wrong with your entity declaration, like, user is an array of UserEntity[] where on the output you have one user, clean it up for sure, check your data collection maybe something is missing

Comment: Also add to select statement select from `apu.*` if you follow this prefix name or yours

Comment: @TheMechanic how did you solve this issue ? 
I have same issue trying to leftJoin two differents columns from table A to table B.
Example: My Table A has column ADMIN(user) and MANAGER(user) which refer to Table B USER(user).

Answer (score 0):

After looking for a while I found a solution:
The second argument of leftJoinAndSelect() is an alias so you have to use different name let say usersA and usersB:

```
const qb = getRepository(LeaveEntity)
  .createQueryBuilder("leave")
  .skip(size * (page - 1))
  .take(size)
  .orderBy('leave.created_at', orderBy)
  .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.approvedBy", "usersA")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("leave.user", "usersB")
  .select(
   [
   'leave', 
   'usersA.email',  
   'usersA.id', 
   'usersA.firstName', 
   'usersA.lastName',
   'usersA.email',  
   'usersB.id', 
   'usersB.firstName', 
   'usersB.lastName'
  ]);
```

And here is my DOG own example tested and working:

```
export class Dog extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedDate: Date;

  @ManyToMany(type => User)
  @JoinTable()
  friends: User[];

  @ManyToMany(type => User)
  @JoinTable()
  owners: User[];

  @ManyToMany(type => Hobby)
  @JoinTable()
  hobbies: Hobby[];

}
```

And here my queryBuilder:

```
let queryBuilder = Dog
  .createQueryBuilder('Dog')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('Dog.hobbies', 'hobby')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('Dog.friends', 'usersA')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('Dog.owners', 'usersB')
  .select(
    [
    'Dog.id',
    'Dog.name',
    'hobby.type',
    'hobby.cost',
    'usersA.id',
    'usersA.username',
    'usersB.id',
    'usersB.username'
  ]
);
```